# Не отображать стиль

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!, нужна помощь, есть класс gaq со стилем border, нужно сделать так чтобы если поле id 127 пустое то не отображать стиль border, заранее спасибо

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `invlist` WHERE `id`=127");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
do
{
echo "

<div class='gaq'>".$data['id']."</div>

 ";
}
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($resultat));
?>
```

Comment: ну так сделайте если поле id 127 пустое - не присваивать этот класс диву.

Comment: это пример , id = $page оно может быть иногда пустым иногда заполненым, так если id = 127 пусто то нужно чтобы div вообще не отображался

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `invlist` WHERE `id`=127");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<div class="gaq"><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: не отображается результат

Comment: Обновил ответ, отвык я уже от голого mysql ))

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно! )